# Not working mysql query with prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to understand where I am wrong with this query..

```
$query = "INSERT INTO turni (data, utenteId, turno_ceduto, tipo_turno_ceduto,
turno_cercato, 
note, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc,$query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'sissss', $data, $utenteId, $turno_ceduto,
$tipo_turno_ceduto, $turno_cercato, $note);

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$count = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
```

Why is $count -1??

Comment: What about mysql errors?

Answer (score 1):

Question

> Why is $count -1??

Answer

> -1 indicates that the query has returned an error

[mysqli_stmt_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php)

You shoud check errors with [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php), it's returns a string description of the last error.

> You get the error description from the last mysqli-function, not from the last mysql-error.

Comment: @user3159187, update your question with mysqli_error and show output of it.

Answer (score 0):

You should *always* check for errors after each prepare() and execute(), and report the errors.

Here's an example:

```
if (($stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc,$query)) === false) {
    trigger_error(mysqli_error($dbc), E_USER_ERROR);
}
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'sissss', $data, $utenteId, $turno_ceduto,
    $tipo_turno_ceduto, $turno_cercato, $note);

if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) === false) {
    trigger_error(mysqli_stmt_error($stmt), E_USER_ERROR);
}
$count = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
```